# yt-dlp: ffmpeg working for some videos, but not for the others

Tags: ffmpeg, chapters, yt-dlp

I started using yt-dlp a few days ago, so I'm new to the whole thing. I needed to download some videos from youtube, but have them split into chapters.

The command:

```
yt-dlp --split-chapters URL
```

seems to be doing the right thing. However, running exactly the same command works for some videos, but for some I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Postprocessing: ffmpeg not found. Please install or provide the path using --ffmpeg-location 'list' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

I have previously installed `ffmpeg` and added it to the PATH and it worked fine, and it doesn't make much sense to me that the command would work for certain URLs if `ffmpeg` wasn't there.

The video for which the error comes up is no different than the one for which the command works. They both have chapters.

Does anyone have an idea what might be happening?

Please do let me know if there is something else I should share -- I'll edit the original post!

Answer (score 1):

yt-dlp does not use ffmpeg for everything. This is why it sometimes works.

yt-dlp has [custom ffmpeg builds](https://github.com/yt-dlp/FFmpeg-Builds) that it recommends for use with their tool.

Comment: However, the repository you indicate has no solution for macOS 

Answer (score 0):

The same has happened to me today on macOS: I had been using `ffmpeg` forever but this morning it could not `--split-chapters`. The issue was not that it was missing or it was not *the correct* build. I solved the issue by uninstalling and reinstalling it using Homebrew. In the process, I was told that Apple Command Line Tools were not installed, which is unlikely true. Nonetheless, I've reinstalled them, and the reinstallation of `ffmpeg` was successful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).